# $(m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0) \Leftrightarrow (\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q)$ [Proof Verification]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, peano-axioms

Please check if my proof has any error! I'm very happy to receive any suggestion to improve my proof. Many thanks for your help.

**Definition:**

> $m \text{ divides } n \Leftrightarrow \exists p, n=pm$.
>
> We denotes $(m \text{ divides } n)$ by $m \mid n,$ and $(m \text{ does not divide } n)$ by $m \not \mid n$.

**Lemma 1:**

> $a \mid b$ and $a \not \mid c \implies a \not \mid (b+c)$

Proof:

> Assuming the contrary, we have $a \mid (b+c)$. This implies $b+c=xa$. Since $a \mid b$, then $b=ya$. So we have $ya+c=xa$.
>
> Clearly, $x \geq y$. So $x=y+r$. Substituting this into equation $ya+c=xa$, we have $ya+c=(y+r)a \implies c=ra \implies a \mid c$ (contradiction).
>
> Thus $(a \mid b$ and $a \not \mid c) \implies a \not \mid (b+c)$.

**Lemma 2:**

> $0<m<n \implies n \not \mid m$

Proof:

> Assuming the contrary, $n \mid m \implies m=pn$.
>
> If $p=0$, then $n=m=0$ (contradiction).
>
> If $p \geq 1$, then $m=pn \geq n$ (contradiction).
>
> Thus, $0<m<n \implies n \not \mid m$.

**Theorem:**

> $(m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0) \Leftrightarrow (\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q)$

Proof:

> 1. We prove $(\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q) \implies (m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0)$.
>
> $m \mid pm$ and $m \not \mid q$ (Applying **Lemma 2** for $0<q<m$) $\implies m \not \mid (pm+q)$, or $m \not \mid n$ (This is due to **Lemma 1**).
>
> $0<q<m \implies m \neq 0$.
>
> Thus $\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q \implies m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0$.
>
> 2. We prove $(m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0) \implies (\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q)$.
>
> Let $T=\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0 \implies \exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q\}$.
>
> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 0=0.m \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, m \mid 0$. Thus $0 \in T$.
>
> Assuming $k \in T$. This implies ($m \not \mid k \wedge m \neq 0 \implies \exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } k=pm+q)$.
>
> Assuming $m \not \mid k+1$ and $m \neq 0$. We have two possible cases: $m \mid k$ and $m \not \mid k$.
>
> a. $m \mid k$
>
> $m \not \mid k+1 \implies m \neq 1$ [Since $\forall (k+1), 1 \mid (k+1)$].
>
> $m \neq 0 \wedge m \neq 1 \implies m>1$ or $1<m$
>
> $m \mid k \implies k=xm \implies (k+1)=xm+1$ in which $0<1<m$.
>
> Thus $(k+1) \in T$.
>
> b. $m \not \mid k$
>
> $(k \in T \wedge m \not \mid k \wedge m \neq 0) \implies \exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } k=pm+q$.
>
> $\implies \exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } (k+1)=pm+(q+1)$.
>
> $\implies \exists p, 0<q+1<m+1 \text{ s.t } (k+1)=pm+(q+1)$.
>
> Since $(k+1)=pm+(q+1)$ and $m \not \mid k+1$, then $(q+1) \neq m$.
>
> $(q+1) \neq m \wedge 0<q+1<m+1 \implies 0<q+1<m$.
>
> As a result, $\exists p, 0<q+1<m \text{ s.t } (k+1)=pm+(q+1)$.
>
> Thus $(k+1) \in T$.
>
> By principle of induction, $T=\mathbb{N}$, or equivalently $(m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0) \implies (\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q)$.
>
> Combining results from 1. and 2. , we have $(m \not \mid n \wedge m \neq 0) \Leftrightarrow (\exists p, 0<q<m \text{ s.t } n=pm+q)$.

Comment: I checked pretty carefully, but did find any mistake: well done!

Comment: Thank you @Bram28 :)) I have been waiting your response. Now i got it ^_^

Comment: You're welcome!  And you're doing very well!  Are you self-studying?

Comment: @Bram28, Yeap ^^ Although I was an undergraduate student in finance. I would like to have a good understanding of Real Analysis, Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, and Topology (introduction level is just enough for me to pursue an PhD in economics). I'm now self-studying Real Analysis by using textbook "A Course in Mathematical Analysis" from prof Garling. I feel wonderful when I know how the number systems are built from scratch and how number properties, which most people take for granted and use frequently every day, are proved rigorously.

Comment: Hey, that's very impressive!  And yes, building up arithmetic from elementary axioms is pretty cool! :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help to answer my questions patiently! You made me feel inspired and motivated!

Comment: :)  You're doing it!